# Bash script : ls command not found

Tags: bash, arch-linux

Under Arch USB iso, zsh, running the script `./test` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$(dirname $0)
ls $PATH
```

returns

> ls: command not found

Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT : ls alone works but not when I'm adding $PATH

Edit : just realized from the comments that $PATH is an environment variable and I was replacing its value...

Comment: You can try to make a ls using for f in *; do echo $f; done , and try to determine the ls location, by this for equivalent for ls. But i think its a path problem.

Comment: Put `echo $PATH` in your script. If it doesn't contain `/bin` then add it.

Comment: It is good to strip a program to its minimum before pasting here, but please ensure that it is no smaller (test that the smaller program still exhibits the fault).

Comment: also tangential to the subject is good to know that shell expands `*` to list files of the current directory so you can always do `echo .* *`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable PATH is a special one. There are a lot of special variables (and all are all capital, so easily avoided). `PATH` holds a list of directories to search for commands.

For fun and learning (though these are the same thing), type `echo $PATH`, outside of script, to see what it has in it.

To fix problem do not break PATH: use a different variable name (not all capitals).

Answer (score 1):

Try `/bin/ls`, it seems that `ls` is not in the path as @123 has mentioned in the comment.

To add `/bin` to the `PATH`. Add in `~/.bashrc`

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/bin
```

Comment: Apart form getting the `export` command wrong (expects a variable name to the left of `=`, not a variable expansion), this does not take into account that the user is using `PATH` as an ordinary variable.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:$(dirname $0)"
ls $PATH
```

This way you're adding `$(dirname $0)` to the PATH variable instead of replacing it. Or, if you don't want to edit the environment variable and want to use `$(dirname $0)` separately, use a different variable name.

Comment: This makes no sense.  The user obviously wants to use `PATH` as a variable holding the script's directory and then wants to view the contents of that directory with `ls`.  Adding the directory to the end of the `PATH` variable would be correct if they want to access executables in that directory without using their absolute path (there is no indication that this is what they want), but listing the `$PATH` value with `ls` is nonsensical.